# Running Camunda BPMN Spring boot using Netty instead of Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, camunda-plugin

I am using Camunda Spring boot starter library for running my Camunda BPMN engine and also done some custom Java implementation. I am planning to run the project using Netty instead of Tomcat servlet. Please help me for running the Java spring boot application with Netty (Reactive way). Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You did not elaborate why you want to do this. Speculating about your requirements, I would recommend to look into Camunda Cloud (possibly self-managed https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/overview/). It uses a different process engine (and Netty) under the hood, which has a complete different modern architecture (no relational DB, CQRS style) and is designed as a cloud native distributed system for highest volumes.